# R - How can I make this loop faster?

Tags: r, performance, loops

Is there some way to make this loop faster in r?

```
    V=array(NA, dim=c(nrow(pixDF), n))

    for(i in 1:n)
    {
       sdC<-sqrt(det(Cov[,i,]))
       iC<-inv(Cov[,i,])
       V[,i]<-apply(pixDF,1,function(x)(sdC*exp(-0.5*((x-Mean[i,])%*%iC%*%as.matrix((x-Mean[i,]))))))
    }
```

where, in this case, `pixDF` is a matrix with 490000 rows and 4 columns filled with doubles. `n` = 5. `Cov` is a (4,5,4) array filled with "doubles". `Mean` is a (5,4) array filled with doubles as well.

This loop was taking about 30min on my computer. (before editing).
Right now it's taking 1min.

Comment: Why is `pixDF` not a matrix? You do a lot of stuff in the `apply` loop that would only need to be calculated once in the surrounding `for` loop, e.g., `sqrt(det(Cov[,i,]))` does not need to be calculated separately for each line of `pixDF`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you include a reproducible example along with expected output. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @Roland I didn't know matrices were more memory efficient. After calculating `sqrt(det(Cov[,i,]))` outside `apply` and using matrix instead of data.frame it didn't change much, but calculating `inv(Cov[, i ,])` before made it much faster (60sec). Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know the `inv` function but if it does what its name says, let me just point out the general advice for numerics: avoid inverting a matrix. It's costly and creates problems with (loss of) precision. Usually, it's better to `solve` the equation system.

Answer (score 1):

As Ronak notes, it is hard to help without reproducible example. But, I think that `apply` could be avoided. Something like this COULD work:

```
V <- array(NA, dim = c(nrow(pixDF), n))
tpixDF <- t(pixDF)
for (i in 1:n) {
  x <- Cov[, i, ]
  sdC <- sqrt(det(x))
  iC <- solve(x)
  mi <- Mean[i, ]
  k <- t(tpixDF - mi)
  V[, i] <- sdC*exp(-0.5*rowSums(k %*% iC * k))
}
```

Also, as Roland mentions `inv` probably is equal `solve`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's even faster now. Sorry, I'm new here, I'll try to give a reproducible example next time. But why is `solve` better (or more precise) than `inv`? And, since your example worked, `*` happens before `%*%`, right?

Comment: @PedroM. From which packages you are using `inv`, you have not mentioned that? For example `pracma::inv` uses `solve` in its code. `%*%` happens first. Try running `k %*% (iC * k)`...

Comment: @PedroM. `solve` is better if you actually use it to solve the matrix equation instead of inverting the matrix, i.e., do `solve(X, y)` instead of `solve(X) %*% y`.